# Node.js Access / Change Variables Inside an HTML <script>

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

If I have a variable inside of an html script:

**index.html:**

```
<html>
...
</html>
<script>
   var example1 = "string"
</script>
```

How do I access the variable example1 in a separate JS file:

**jsfile.js**

```
var example2 = example1
```

**Example File Directory:**

- src

  - index.html
- jsfile.js

Comment: I'm afraid your question is quite vague. Are you asking how to parse HTML (to get the script tag) and JavaScript (to get the variable and its initializer)? Or...?

Comment: You can try a global variable like window.example1 ="string";
var example2 = window.example;

Answer (score 0):

You can use `window` variable. On your HTML page change `var example1` with `window.example1` like this:

```html
<html>
...
</html>
<script>
   window.example1 = "string"
</script>
```

And on your js file you can get this variable data with `window.example1` :

```
var example2 = window.example1
```

---

[Example on Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ndeq7boL/)

Comment: I tried this, and get ReferenceError: window is not defined